How to bump version from Conventional Commits in react js
I'm using conventional commits and commit according to this.
And Here is one of my commit:
git commit -m "fix(TCM-1010): Web App / Manage Item Templates: The last item template in the table is cut off. Also the actions for this item are cut off"
Now I want want to do version bump from this commit how can I do that ?
I try to figerout some npm packages but it's not suitable.Here my project's details:
"react": "^16.10.2",
"node": "v16.20.2"

